# Retain the value of a variable in php until the success

Tags: php, html

I am using the same PHP from 2 different html pages. I am trying to retain the value of a variable when the PHP page is submitted once again. Below is my code for your reference.

```
$upload = "E:/Dem";

$str = '';

if(isset($_POST['userid'],$_POST['pid']))
{
  $userid = trim($_POST["userid"]);
  $pid = trim($_POST["pid"]);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM template WHERE uname = '$userid' and pword = '$pid'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  echo "公司".'<br/>';
  echo $row['client'].'<br/>'.'<br/>';
  echo "第".'<br/>';
  echo '<a href="upload.html"/>'.$row['day1'].'</a>'.'<br/>';

 $target = $upload.'/'.$row['week'].'/'.$row['day1'].'/'.$row['client'].'/'.$row['brand'].'/'.$row['sc'].'/';


  $imagename = $row['week'].'.'.$row['day1'].'.'.$row['client'].'.'.$row['brand'].'.'.$row['sn'].'.'.'jpg';
  if($str == '')
  {

      $str = $target;

      }
   if(!file_exists($target))
   {
     mkdir($target,null,0777);
   }
  $img = $imagename; 

}

//echo "$target";
echo "$str".'<br/>';
echo "$img".'<br/>';
if(isset($_FILES['image']))

// image upload  
// Want the value of target here.
  {
      $image = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
      echo $str;
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $str.$img);
      echo "<P>FILE UPLOADED TO: $str</P>";
  }
```

When this PHP is called from the first html page. I am storing the value in $str. The value of $str = $target when this PHP is called from first html page. I want to retain the value of this $str when this PHP is called again from the second HTML page. I want to use the value of this $str to move the uploaded file to the folders and sub-folders created at run-time as shown in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `session` variable to store the value of `$str` in it and use that session variable across multiple pages.

```
$_SESSION['str'] = $str;
```

how to use session: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: look at the edited answer of mine. If you do not know how to use sessions then refer the link.

Comment: @Saurabh: Have you gone through the code i put here. I want to use this $str to upload the image. Can you please let me know how to use this $_SESSION['str'] = $str into the second if condition.

Comment: @AnuragLal, yes i saw your question, use that session variable where you wish to use, i cannot provide you the complete tutorial of sessions that is the reason i gave you the link to refer to how to use session

Comment: @Saurabh. Thanks a lot for the link buddy. And i am asking you to give me a whole tutorial, i tried using the method mentioned in the W3School but it didnt work so i posted this thing here to get the answers from experts who have hands on experience using SESSIONS.

Comment: @AnuragLal, did you apply `session_start()` in each page where you tried using session variable?